# Implementing a Yearly Subscription

Tags: android

I am developing an app for Android with Android Studio.
My questions are:
"How do I implement A Yearly Subscription for my app? I want the app to not be usable if they don't have a current subscription-how do I do that?

I know that I have to go to the developer area in Google play and setup subscriptions, and that I need a product ID, but what about code in my app? Is there a library, set of code, or an easy way to accomplish what I need? I know I need an API, but where do I add it in my app? I am lost...

**Again, all I want is for my app to have a yearly subscription, and the app should not work unless the yearly subscription is paid.**

I have went here, and again it only tells me about the play console-nothing about adding code into my app. [Google Play Create a Subscription](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en) I don't know what I need or where to code for it...

*Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

First create a payment profile with Play Console and follow **all** instructions at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7161426
including the pages on the right side of the page.

**Step 2**

Incorporate billing into your app using the billing API described here
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api

Comment: I have read over these as well, and did just read through them again. I guess starting at the beginning so I can understand, I get Step #1, that looks like the easy part.

Comment: I know I need to make an AIDL file correct? Is that the only file I need to make?

Comment: If you want to use in-app billing then you need to use the AIDL interface to implement features of in-app billing. Alternatively, you can use the Google Play Billing Library to integrate one-time payment or subscription features into your app. The Google Play Billing Library is here https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview. The AIDL interface is here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api