# Need clarity on implementing a subscription app

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, google-play-console

I've developed an Android app and need clarity on what is required to offer it, via Google Play Store, as a subscription app (i.e. offer use of the app for a monthly fee). For now, no in-app purchases or in-app subscriptions are planned; the only subscription is for use of the app itself. All of the documentation I've read about subscriptions from the Google Play Store seems only to discuss in-app subscriptions.
**My questions:**
1) Is an overall app subscription treated/processed the same as an in-app subscription (i.e. via the app)?
2) If not, what portions of the Google documentation/guides on subscriptions do I implement? Everything that isn't expressly mentioned as being for in-app subscriptions/purchases?
3) Do I need a back-end server to manage/track app subscription info, or can subscriptions at the app level be managed via Google Play Console?
4) Is there a guide/example/tutorial somewhere that clearly explains how to implement what seems like a basic solution, a subscription app with no in-app purchases?

*Examples of what I found during research:*
[Create a subscription - Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504) indicates:

> Create a subscription
>
> Using Google Play Billing, you can offer **in-app products** that charge users for content or services on a recurring basis, known as subscriptions. Subscriptions can include items like a collection of apps, games, or other **content for a recurring fee within your app** on Google Play.

In Google Play Console, subscriptions are only mentioned (from what I can see) under Store presence->**In App Products**->Subscriptions

I reviewed other questions on SO related to subscriptions, but virtually all appear to be focused on in-app subscriptions. One exception was [Implementing a Yearly Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633707/implementing-a-yearly-subscription). Per the answer from GNUzilla, I understand the need to create a payment profile in Play Console. The second part of GNUzilla's answer references the now deprecated AIDL interface, so I instead reviewed the guide page for its replacement, [Use the Google Play Billing Library | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview). However, this also appears focused on in-app subscriptions. For example,

> Enable the purchase of an **in-app product**
>
> ...
>
> To start a **purchase request from your app**, call the launchBillingFlow() method from the UI thread. Pass a reference to a BillingFlowParams object containing the relevant data to complete the purchase, such as the product ID (skuId) of the item and product type (SkuType.INAPP for a one-time product or SkuType.SUBS for a subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Is an overall app subscription treated/processed the same as an in-app subscription (i.e. via the app)?**

There is no such app subscription feature Google has implemented. It always will be in-app subscriptions. User will download the app free/paid and login/signup into the app then the developer will show the subscriptions plan based upon the business case.

2. **If not, what portions of the Google documentation/guides on subscriptions do I implement? Everything that isn't expressly mentioned as being for in-app subscriptions/purchases?**

In-App subscriptions. Check here https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions

3. **Do I need a back-end server to manage/track app subscription info, or can subscriptions at the app level be managed via Google Play Console?**

Yes, you need the backend for managing the real-time notifications. If you don't want to have the backend then you will miss lots of scenarios like your app don't what is the current subscription status. It is also good from a security point of view to verify the purchase in the backend.

4. **Is there a guide/example/tutorial somewhere that clearly explains how to implement what seems like a basic solution, a subscription app with no in-app purchases?**

You can check google [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions). In the future, I will also publish the blog regarding this.

Comment: So, if the only cost is the subscription, is it listed as a free download with in-app purchases? Also, where will the blog be posted?

Comment: Where will your blog be published?

Comment: Sorry bro, I am not able to post the blog due to some other commitments.. Answer of your question - yes your app will be listed as free download with in-app purchases tag